# Does the Samsung Smart TV use WebKit?

Tags: webkit, samsung-smart-tv

I am new to Samsung Smart TV Development, and I want to know if they are using WebKit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

2010 and 2011 devices use Maple. The version 3.0 SDK suggests they are moving to Webkit for 2012 devices.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, which has *never* been wrong, the Maple platform was based off the same Gecko engine as Firefox 3. The latest devices report Maple2012 in the user agent string along with AppleWebKit(534.7).

Answer (score 4):

check [this](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Devtools/Sdkdownload) page telling you: App Engine (Webkit Core)

and for versions and SDK check this [link](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Devtools/Spec).

Answer (score 3):

Model UN46ES7100F does as of November 2012 (and likely before). The user agent string is:

`Mozilla/5.0 (SMART-TV; X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/534.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0 Safari/534.7`